# DSpat::create.lines and spatstat::rlinegrid: Adding too many lines?

Tags: r, sp, spatstat

Does anybody know of an issue with either DSpat's `create.lines` or spatstat's `rlinegrid`? Whenever I use these functions on my Windows (owins), the output has far too many lines.

For example, if I run

```
DSpat::create.lines(owint, nlines=80, width = 1, spacing=NULL,angle=0)
```

The output has approx. 2000 lines.

If I do a bit of math so I can set the number of lines output from `rlinegrid`, based on window diameter:

```
  dot <- diameter.owin(owin)

  d8 <- (dot / 80)

  rlgt <- rlinegrid(angle = 0, spacing = d8, as.owin(owint))
```

The output also has approx. 2000 lines.

Simplifying the owin by converting to `sp` and using `gSimplify`, then running through the above functions works for the most part, but sometimes the functions still output too many lines.

The shape I am adding lines to is similar to this:

[image]

Am I misunderstanding how `rlinegrid` and `create.lines` work?

Note: The code to import the image and run through all the code previous to this issue is very long and arduous, but I can upload it if an example is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this problem, and you have not provided a working example which demonstrates the problem.

My example:

```
 library(spatstat)
 dot <- diameter(letterR)
 d8 <- dot/80
 rl <- rlinegrid(angle=0, spacing=d8, win=letterR)
 rl
```

This gives a pattern of line segments (class `psp`) comprising about 100-130 segments, formed by intersecting a grid of about 80 equally-spaced straight lines with the non-convex window `letterR`.

You could check that your calculated value of `d8` was sensible.